# Does cataract condition cause red film when sun is shining?

Tags: pathology, vision, eyes, light

Since two years ago I have a red film in my field of vision when the sunlight (or a white spot) is at the border (or even lightly behind) of the vision field, the red color is especially obvious at the shadows or dark places (it seems logical that the film color is more visible where there is less light).
My eye doctor recently diagnosed a little bit opalescence of my eyes, that is, a beginning cataract.

So my question is simple : does cataract condition cause a red film when sun is shining at the vision field border ?

I have an explanation for this : at the eye border the white sun light goes trough the skin and is colored red by the blood, then because of opalescence the red light propagates into the whole vision field, thus creating a red film. So if this explanation is correct then any people with a cataract condition should see a red film in such situation, that is what I want to check. Should be quite simple.

(Without strong spots there is still a mild gray film, making black appearing grayish and making shades differences less obvious to see than before this condition. Vision tests on green or red background doesn't make any differences)

Comment: "Should be quite simple." What research have you done to try to answer this question? Have you read about cataracts and 'redness of vision"? FWIW, most early cataracts are completely asymptomatic. Almost everyone gets them as they age.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I find no info about relation of vision redness with sun and cataract, so it seems that it has nothing to do with cataract, but I want to be sure of this. And this "should be quite simple" to check as I have a very early cataract, so anyone with a cataract, even with very early one, should be in the same situation as me.

Comment: Exactly! You have answered your own question. Millions of people have early (and asymptomatic) cataracts (myself included) and this is not a reported resultant effect.